# Data management with shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im starting with shell script programming in linux and i need help to solve the following problem:

I need to read from a file.txt the following information

```
lastName,Name |age | gender | antiquity | profession | response time
Homes,Louis 34 male 12 leader 4
House,Jonathan 26 male 4 designer 7
Smith,Peter 36 male 10 architect 8  
Prat,Zoe 40 female 14 programmer 2
Evans,Bethany 30 female 8 programmer 12
```

with the information I need:

- Profession of the two oldest professionals.
- Average time of the two professionals who have less response time
- Age and gender of the older professional.

Tried with the following code, but it does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
    do
    antigüedad=$(echo $line|cut -d" " -f4)
    if [[$antiquity -gt $greaterAge]]
        then
            greaterAge=$antiquity
            moreOld=$line
    fi
done < data.txt
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to read the lines and then worry about extracting the fields.  You can directly read the fields into separate variables since you have a delimited file:

```
while read -r name age gender antiquity profession response_time; do
  # your logic here
  # you need a space after `[[` and before `]]` in `[[ ... ]]` condition
done < <(sed 1d file.txt)
```

See this post for more details:

- [Looping through the content of a file in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601)